# I am trying to render a filtered list of objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays, search

I have a sample list of which is an array of objects with three fields in the App component. The list is passed as a prop to an "booksearch" component which handles the logic to search and filter the list based on search text. below is the JSX which renders the book. I am doubting issue is with the "matcheBook" method.

```
<div className="output-container">
    {this.props.books
        .filter((e) => this.matchesBook(e))
        .map((b) => (
            <div className="output-card" key={b.title}>
                {Object.entries(b).map(([k, v]) => (
                    <div key={v} className="out-section">
                        <span className="heading">
                            <b>{k}</b>
                        </span>
                       <span className="details">{v}</span>
                    </div>
                ))}
          </div>
       ))}
</div>
```

method for handling the search text

```
handleChange(evt, name) {
    let searchText = evt.target.value;
        this.setState((state) => ({
            ...state,
            fields: {
                ...state.fields,
                [name]: searchText
        }
    }));
}
```

filtering logic

```
matchesBook(book) {
    const { fields } = this.state;
        return Object.entries(book).some(
            ([k, v]) =>
                !fields[k] ||
                v.toString()
                 .toLowerCase()
                 .includes(fields[k].toString().trim().toLowerCase())
           );
}
```

State shape

```
this.state = {
    fields: initialFields
};
```

"initialFields" comes from below

```
const fieldsArray = ["author", "title", "year"];

const initialFields = fieldsArray.reduce(
    (a, e) => ({
        ...a,
        [e]: ""
      }),
    {}
 );
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/booksearch-ln398z?file=/src/BookSearch.jsx)

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution where I ran a Array.prototype.every on values of the search object and Array.prototype.some on the book object

```
matchesBook(book) {
    const { fields } = this.state;
    return Object.values(fields)
        .every(v => v === "") || 
        Object.entries(book)
            .some(([k, v]) => 
                fields[k] !== "" && v.toString()
               .toLowerCase()
               .includes(fields[k].trim().toLowerCase()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried some() function, but doing the search function code on my own way I modified your **matchesBook** function into this one:

```
matchesBook(book) {
  const { fields } = this.state;

  let matching = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < Object.entries(fields).length; i++) {
    if (Object.entries(fields)[i][1] === "") {
      matching++;
    } else {
      if(String(Object.entries(book)[i][1]).toLowerCase().includes(String(Object.entries(fields)[i][1]).toLowerCase())){
        matching++;
      }
    }
  }
  return matching === Object.entries(fields).length;
}
```

Try it, it'll work!

Comment: Good one, but still want to find out what's wrong with that logic!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#description) `some()` method executes the `callbackFn` function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where `callbackFn` returns a ***truthy*** value (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). **If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns true.**

In your case `!fields[k]` always return true when its value is `""` and so it never have to compare succeeding values in the array which contains the field we are checking, in this case `year`. Please see example below.

```js
const book = {
    author: "Charles Dickens",
    title: "The Pickwick Papers",
    year: "1837"
  };

const fields = {author: "", title: "", year: "lookinforthisstringinbook"};

const checkValue = Object.entries(book).some(
    ([k, v]) =>
        !fields[k] || // --> always returns true
        v.toString()
         .toLowerCase()
         .includes(fields[k].toString().trim().toLowerCase())
   );

console.log(checkValue)
```

Comment: yes, it was returning true always for "". Figuring out how to get a falsy value;